# Perl: print hash contents in a table

Tags: perl, hash

Could anyone provide me direction to print the contents of a scalable 2D hash in form of a table.

A sample output

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1  0   1   2   -
R2  3   x   y   5
R3  4   3   -   2
R4  6   6   6   2
```

The contents above are available in the Hash and where there is missing data, the output is represented by '-'. The number and columns in the output are not fixed.

regards

Comment: Try it yourself and then we can help you when you get stuck.

Comment: Hello Andy, I have been looking at text-table and others but the problem is not scalable. I am looking for other ideas and I didnt share my current example to avoid clouding your thinking process.

Comment: That's not how it works.  It's not about our thinking process, but helping with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -MData::Dumper -lane'
  @c=@F, next if $. ==1;
  $k = shift @F;
  @{ $h{$k} }{@c} = @F;
  }{ print Dumper \%h;
' file
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'R3' => {
                'C3' => '-',
                'C4' => '2',
                'C2' => '3',
                'C1' => '4'
              },
      'R1' => {
                'C3' => '2',
                'C4' => '-',
                'C2' => '1',
                'C1' => '0'
              },
      'R4' => {
                'C3' => '6',
                'C4' => '2',
                'C2' => '6',
                'C1' => '6'
              },
      'R2' => {
                'C3' => 'y',
                'C4' => '5',
                'C2' => 'x',
                'C1' => '3'
              }
    };
```

Comment: I don't know if it answered the question, but I definitely learned something from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ooga no problem, is there anything I should clarify?